# Create a '.desktop' shortcut for 'Show Applications' on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome-shell, .desktop, dock, plank

I need to create a `.desktop` shortcut for '*Show Applications*', so that I can pin it to the Plank dock to view all applications and search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First install `xdotool` by running the following command in Terminal

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

The key combination <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> shows the 'Show Applications' screen. The following command will simulate this specific combination

```
xdotool key super+a
```

So create a simple `.desktop` launcher and use the command above for the `Exec=` entry.

Answer (score 3):

Although the answer above is the accepted and will certainly work if you use the xorg display server, following command directly "commands" Gnome Shell to show the applications overview.

```
dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.overview.show(); if (! Main.overview.viewSelector._showAppsButton.checked) {Main.overview.viewSelector._showAppsButton.checked = true;} else {Main.overview.hide();};'
```

So create a simple `.desktop` launcher and use the command above for the `Exec =` entry.

Whereas `xdotool` may not work reliably on Wayland, this approach will also work on Wayland without issues.

Comment: +1 I prefer this answer over the accepted one, as it works on wayland too. (Even though I am using Xorg)

Answer (score 1):

I actually created a lightweight deb installer to do this, check out my repo here https://github.com/milan102/Ubuntu-Launchpad

The installation instructions are in the github README. The program is a simple shell script that invokes the keyboard shortcut for showing applications (Super + A)